Python get png AND bounding boxes from SVG with chrome
I have a python script that converts SVGs to PNG using chrome to render it. This works great, but I also need to get bounding boxes of the SVG groups. This can be done by including JavaScript code in the script tag:
function toJson(group) {
    const bbox = group.getBBox();
    const groupInfo = {
        class: group.getAttribute('class') || 'null',
        x: bbox.x,
        y: bbox.y,
        width: bbox.width,
        height: bbox.height
    };
    // Get all child <g> elements and add them to the children array
    const childGroups = group.querySelectorAll('g');
    const children = [];
    childGroups.forEach(childGroup => {
        children.push(toJson(childGroup));
    });
    // Only add the children array if it is not empty
    if (children.length > 0) {
        groupInfo.children = children;
    }
    return groupInfo;
}

However, I can not obtain this output. I tried downloading a file which does not work consistently because I use chrome in headless mode. I also tried getting the output of JavaScript's console.log, but these are only logged internally and can not received from the python subprocess.
I need this to run very quickly and multithreaded.
Is there a way to receive data from subprocess' JavaScript code like that?
My python script so far:
import os, argparse
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import subprocess


def get_svg_dimensions(svg_file):
    # Parse the SVG file and extract width and height
    tree = ET.parse(svg_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    width = root.get('width')
    height = root.get('height')
    # Remove 'px' and convert to integers
    width_value = int(width.replace('px', ''))
    height_value = int(height.replace('px', ''))
    return width_value, height_value

def render(tmpDir, width, height, iSvg, oPng):
    width = int(width)
    height = int(height)
    html = f"""<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Title</title>
        </head>
        <body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden">
        <img style="padding; margin:0" src="{iSvg}" width="{width}" height="{height}"></img>
        <script>
        // TODO reading the SVG can be done but how to get this data
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
      """
    htmlFile = tmpDir / "icon.html"
    with htmlFile.open("w") as f:
        f.write(html)
    command = ["chrome.exe",
               "--headless",
               f"--screenshot={oPng}",
               f"--window-size={width},{height}",
               "--default-background-color=ffffff",
               "--force-device-scale-factor=1",     # stop scaling down for larger resolutions
               str(htmlFile)
               ]
    try:
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error: 'chrome.exe' was not found in your PATH variable. Please add path to chrome.exe like this 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application' to your PATH variable.")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='svg2png.py [-h] [-W width] [-H height] [-o output] <input>')
    parser.add_argument("-W", "--width", type=int, help="Width (default from SVG)", default=None)
    parser.add_argument("-H", "--height", type=int, help="Height (default from SVG)", default=None)
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="Output file (default to current dir)")
    parser.add_argument("input", help="SVG file to convert")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    input = Path(os.path.realpath(args.input))
    output = Path(os.path.realpath(args.output)) if args.output else input.parent / f"{input.stem}.png"

    # If width and height are not provided, get them from the SVG
    if args.width is None or args.height is None:
        if Path(args.input).is_file():
            width, height = get_svg_dimensions(args.input)
            if args.width is None:
                args.width = width
            if args.height is None:
                args.height = height

    # Render
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpDir:
        tmpDir = Path(tmpDir)
        render(tmpDir, args.width, args.height, input, output)


